# How to model exponential time decay component with linear regression?

Tags: r, regression, python, generalized-linear-model, regression-coefficients

I was wondering if there was a way to run a regression on a formula that is not exactly a straightforward $Y=\beta X + \varepsilon$

Essentially what I have is a bunch of features $x_i$, with an exponentially decaying time component to them that I'm trying to fit to.

Let's say I label my time component as $x_0$, and the rest of my features are $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$... in this case, each feature will have two coefficients: one for the normal feature significance, $\beta_i$, and another for the "time decay" that i'm trying to factor in: $\beta_{\text{t}i}$

Something like:

$$ Y = \beta_{1} x_1 * e^{(\beta_{t1} x_0)} + \beta_{2} x_2 * e^{(\beta_{t2} x_0)} + \beta_{3} x_3 * e^{(\beta_{t3} x_0)} + \varepsilon$$

How would I model that in either R or Python? This is still linear right? If not, then how else would I fit to this time decay component?

---

**Some final clarifications, based on similar, but not the same questions I've seen on this stackexchange:**

- Time ($x_0$) is known for all datapoints
- There are only three features aside from time
- I would like some confidence measures such as t-stats, which is why I really want to find a way to make it work with Linear Regression packages
- I am open to using anything in R or Python as long as it provides interpretable results

Comment: This model is interesting because it is not linear in either the variables or the parameters.  It's a little strange insofar as the error $\varepsilon$ nevertheless is additive (and therefore, implicitly, of constant variability).  Is this really the case?  Could you explain the motivation for or the origin of this model?  Also, could you describe how the data are sampled?  For instance, is this a time series (with observations over regular time intervals)?

Comment: yep, time series data over regular time intervals. This is an attempt to describe the radiation decay of an observed element in relation to it's size, mass, and some other component that is a little harder to explain. Essentially, the bigger it is, the more (or less?) it may be susceptible to decay based on time passed. Same with the other features. If no time has passed e^0=1 so no decay, but radiation will still be based on the basic coefficients. Hope that helps!

Comment: The thing is there are multiple observations, so we're trying to find a single best approximation across all our observations (knowing it will not be 100% correct of course)

Comment: Wouldn't such a model instead take the form $Y = \exp(-t[\beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 x_3]) + \varepsilon$? (I use "$t$" instead of $x_0$ to emphasize the special role of time.) This supposes $Y$ is measured with independent errors of comparable sizes and otherwise the decay constant is a linear combination of the values of the three explanatory variables. I'm having a hard time seeing  how the model you have proposed reflects any established physical theory, because it does not describe first-order decay of a homogeneous substance.

Comment: So the problem with that would be that at $t=0$, $Y=1$ across the board. I want there to be some baseline estimate at $t=0$ based on the features, that's where the other coefficients $\beta_i$ come into play. At which point it becomes a basic linear regression: $Y=\beta_1x_1+\beta_2x_2+ \beta_3x_3 + \varepsilon$

Comment: it's not exactly radiation decay, I used that as a proxy for the actual phenomenon. it's a little hard to explain, this is supposed to be for work and i'm a little too ashamed to reach out to my boss in all honesty. I'm a new hire and was tasked with improving an existing model that over the years was hacked up to look like the form i just mentioned

Comment: You can accommodate the value of $Y$ at the origin by including an intercept: $Y = \exp(\beta_0-t[\beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 x_3]) + \varepsilon.$ I am concerned that the model you have formulated, interesting as it is, might not be appropriate for your data, so it would help to know enough about what you are studying to determine what a useful model might be.

Comment: I'm unfortunately stuck with the general template due to the way it's implemented currently... was hoping there was just a way to formulate this relation in terms of a regression approach

Comment: sorry if this isn't a lot to go off of, but i'm somewhat stuck myself :/

Comment: Are the values of the $x_i$ constant or can they vary with time?

Comment: They decrease exponentially with time

Comment: I'm asking about the values of the $x_i,$ not the values of $x_i\exp(\beta_{ti}x_0).$ This is a crucial issue: if there are just three values of the $x_i$ that remain the same for all times, it can be impossible to fit this model; but if the $x_i$ themselves vary over time, the problem becomes feasible.

Comment: @whuber oh, my bad. Yeah some can vary with time. But if that’s a problem i can ignore those features